# New to XML Coding and receiving this error. error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element

I'm doing a VERY BASIC CODE JUST FROM NOTHING TO GET BETTER.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">





<textview
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_app"
        android:text="@string/action_settings" ></textview>




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to have spaces at the end of the TextView tag.

1. Remove the " " at the end of the tag.
2. Replace `<textview>` with `<TextView>`

This should work:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:text="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: thanks that fixed it! Now i'm getting duplicate attributes with the code ; <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <textview
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_app"
        android:text="@string/action_settings"/>

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

```
// I Modify your code now try it.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_app" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags are case-sensitive, so use:

```
<Textview
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="0dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome_app"
    android:text="@string/action_settings" >
</Textview>
```